# Getting binary data from a JSON object

Tags: java, android, json

I'm receiving this response from a RESTful service and saving it to a JSONObject:

```
{
    "GetCampaignsInProgressListResult": [
        108,
        162,
        171,
        103,
        185,
        147,
        218,
        16,
        67,
        226,
        44,
        // etc etc
    ]
}
```

The data above represents a binary array. I am trying to read it with the following code:

```
String rawResponse = client.getResponse();
JSONArray entries = null;
JSONObject o = new JSONObject(rawResponse);
entries = new JSONArray(o.getString("GetCampaignsInProgressListResult"));
```

I would like to access the binary data and save it to a byte array, but since it does not have an attributes name I can't use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < entriesLength; i++) {
    JSONObject entry = entries.getJSONObject(i);
    Object something = entry.getString("SomeTag");
}
```

How can I access the binary array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
    String rawResponse = client.getResponse();
    JSONArray entries = null;
    JSONObject o = new JSONObject(rawResponse);
    entries = new JSONArray(o.getString("GetCampaignsInProgressListResult"));
    byte[] bArr = new byte[entries.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < entries.length(); i++) {
        bArr[i] = (byte) entries.getInt(i);
    }
```

Comment: I think it throws `JSONException` saying that `JSONArray[0] is not a number.` On the following line: `bArr[i] = (byte) entries.getInt(i);`